# How to make a request in protractor config file

Tags: curl, protractor

I want to use the below curl request to retrieve information from browserstack to get information on a particular session id.

```
curl -u "xx:xx" https://api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/<session-id>.json
```

I am trying to do something like :

```js
afterEach: function() {
  request({
    uri: `https://${this.user}:${this.key}@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/${browser.sessionId}.json`,
    method: 'PUT'
});
```

This request however does nothing. My requirement is to get the session information.

Appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of restler or http client to retrieve the json response of session information by passing your session id to the request url